# what's the correct SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

The script for mysql database is as follow:

```
Create Table Aircraft
(
    aid integer not null,
    aname nchar(30) not null,
    cruisingrange integer not null,
    primary key (aid)   
);


Create Table Flights
(
    flNo integer not null,
    flFrom nchar(20)not null,
    flTo nchar(20) not null,
    distance integer not null,
    departs time not null,
    arrives time not null,
    price Decimal(6,2) not null,
    primary key(flNo)
);


create table Pilots
(
    pid integer not null,
    pname nchar(20) not null,
    salary Decimal(6,2) not null,
    primary key(pid)
);


create table certified
(
    pid integer not null,
    aid integer not null,
    primary key(pid,aid),
    foreign key(pid) references Pilots(pid)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    foreign key(aid) references Aircraft(aid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO Aircraft(aid,aname,cruisingrange)
VALUES
(1, 'B-450',10000),
(2, 'C-190',4000),
(3, 'RN-110',5000),
(4, 'kp-30',2000),
(5, 'sh-60',1500),
(6, 'mr-70',7000),
(7, 'VK-20',3500);


INSERT INTO Flights(flNo,flFrom,flTo,distance,departs,arrives,price)
VALUES
(100,'city1','city2',1200,'16:00:00','16:30:00',130),
(110,'city3','city4',1000,'18:00:00','19:00:00',160),
(112,'city5','city6',2000,'15:00:00','16:00:00',185),
(115,'city7','city8',4000,'14:00:00','16:00:00',250),
(118,'city9','city3',1500,'18:00:00','19:00:00',220),
(119,'city2','city3',2500,'20:00:00','21:30:00',180);


INSERT INTO Pilots(pid,pname,salary)
VALUES
(400,'jack',150),
(410,'pit',180),
(420,'nami',200),
(430,'rafel',110),
(440,'linda',300);


INSERT INTO Certified(pid,aid)
VALUES 
(400,1),
(400,6),
(410,1),
(420,1),
(420,3),
(420,7),
(440,4),
(440,6);
```

I want a query to find the name of Aircrafts that ALL of Pilots certified for them have a salary more than 187$. In fact, that "ALL" is my problem! could anyone please help me?

Comment: It's generally easier to find "ALL" than "some/someone" :p No fuss needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rephrase the problem as finding the planes whose certified pilots' minimum salary is at least $187.

This is simple to convert to SQL:

```
SELECT aid
FROM ... all your joins here ...
GROUP BY aid
HAVING MIN(salary) >= 187
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a pre-query of just those pilots who have the $187 you are looking for, then find the planes they are certified with...

```
select
      QualifiedPilots.*,
      A.AName,
      A.CruisingRange
   from
      ( select 
              P.*
           from
              Pilots P
           where
              P.Salary >= 187 ) as QualifiedPilots
         JOIN Certified C
            on QualifiedPilots.pid = C.pid
            JOIN Aircraft A
               on C.aid = A.aid
```

With the question and your comment as vague on what you wanted OUT, I've revised to include a group_concat on a per-pilot basis.

```
select
      QualifiedPilots.*,
      group_concat( A.AName ) CertAircraft
   from
      ( select 
              P.*
           from
              Pilots P
           where
              P.Salary >= 187 ) as QualifiedPilots
         JOIN Certified C
            on QualifiedPilots.pid = C.pid
            JOIN Aircraft A
               on C.aid = A.aid
   group by
      QualifiedPilots.pid
```

This result shows only 2 pilots... showing pilot "nami" certified with 3 aircraft, and "linda" certified with 2 aircraft... total of 5 qualified certifications which is what the first query returns... just has the same name multiple times, but shows the aircraft detail.

Comment: @nazila, what's incorrect about it (although you selected another answer).  I am getting all pilots who's salary is AT LEAST the 187 you were looking for.  From that join to what each pilot is certified to, then get that certified aircraft's information by aircraft ID.  What's wrong with that....

Comment: I don't know what's incorrect about it! but if you check the data the result should contains 3 records but your the result of your query contains more records.

Comment: @nazila, revised answer for possible clarification